# Transaction I didn't make is unconfirmed

Tags: wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

I have an unconfirmed transaction that's come from my ledger wallet that I didn't make.

The transaction doesn't show in the wallet history but the balance is now zero.
Can anyone advise? I'm a bit new to this and have a horrible fear I'm going to lose my bitcoin to a hacker:

https://blockchain.info/address/1JKuZqSPA9zLAP2XS96zGUyuGR1awcB5bP

Comment: Are you the sender or the recipient of this transaction?

Comment: It came from my wallet but I didn't make it, nor want it to happen.

Comment: There's good news and bad news.  The good news is that this transaction was sent without a fee, meaning it is unlikely to be included into a block in a timely manner (if at all).  The bad news is that it was created without opting into replace-by-fee, meaning you could "cancel" this transaction by sending another one with a higher fee.  This would have been your best option.  Likely, this transaction will never be mined and will be purged from the mempool.  When that happens, you should spend it to a safer wallet.

Comment: are you saying it will never be mined and returned? Or do I need to kick start that by sending another transaction to 1JKuZqSPA9zLAP2XS96zGUyuGR1awcB5bP  using a higher fee that I don't pay for?

Comment: Only send a transaction to an address you want to pay.  If that isn't an address you want to give money to, then don't.  As for sending another transaction with the same inputs, you can try, but until the unconfirmed transaction is cleared from the mempool, other nodes won't relay it.

Comment: No I don't want it to go through, guess I'll hold it out for it's hopeful safe return.
 And as you say move to a safer wallet, very disappointed my ledger wallet is compromised. A secondary worry is that it gets returned there and the same things happens.